# Collapsible list w/ inline styles - possible?

Tags: html, css, styles, inline

Hi I'm looking to make some changes to the below code, which represents a collapsible/expandable list in HTML and CSS.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.row { vertical-align: top; height:auto !important; }
.list {display:none; }
.show {display: none; }
.hide:target + .show {display: inline; }
.hide:target {display: none; }
.hide:target ~ .list {display:inline; }
@media print { .hide, .show { display: none; } }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
<a href="#hide1" class="hide" id="hide1">Expand</a>
<a href="#show1" class="show" id="show1">Collapse</a>
<div class="list">
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The css between the tags  and  in the form of an internal style sheet, but I would like it all to be included as inline styles instead. Is this possible? Thank you for reading!

Comment: Why would you do that? It’s impossible, as @Quentin describes, but the real problem that you would try to address this way might still be solvable. But I wonder what it might be.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.

The style attribute contains the body of a rule-set.

Your code depends on the use of selectors — including psuedo-classes and combinators — which appear outside the body of the rule-set.